# Save a response Request.post token in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, protractor

I just need to take the token returned in API to complete a URL. I need to take the response.body and save in a variable to use after.

I'm using the protractor to automation tests, and to open a URL I'm consuming an API that return a token, to be used as a parameter in a URL

```js
describe('TEste API', function(){
    var Request = require('request');
    it("api Testing in protractor", async function (callback) {
        let tokenReturn = "empty";

        tokenReturn = Request.post({
            "headers": { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, 
            "url": "https://corpqa.sts.ford.com/adfs/oauth2/token",
            "form": {
                "grant_type":'client_credentials',
                "client_id":'ad9cdf61-e863-4606-a90a-cf7b7141234',
                "client_secret":'QmjeT5UZ0N1M0jOEcggrxgFzw-vrZY2UphAy21d5',
                "resource":'urn:age:pcf:sss:dev',
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.dir(error); 
            }
            resp = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log("inside: " + resp.access_token);

            callback();
        });
        console.log("outside: www.example.com/?token=" + tokenReturn);
    });                                                                     
});//------------------------- end describe
```

In console show me.

outside:

```
www.example.com/?token=[object Object]
```

inside:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IldzZks3Q2FtMDZKY3dkR1Z6a2NiYVUzd21wZyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ1cm46YWdlOnBjZjpzdGY6ZGV2IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jb3JwcWEuc3RzLmZvcmQuY29tL2FkZnMvc2VydmljZXMvdHJ1c3QiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzMyMzIzNjYsImV4cCI6MTU3MzIzNTk2NiwiYXBwdHlwZSI6IkNvbmZpZGVudGlhbCIsImFwcGlkIjoiYWQ5Y2RmNjEtZTg2My00NjA2LWE5MGEtY2Y3YjcxNDE4OTQ1IiwiYXV0aG1ldGhvZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbm1ldGhvZC9wYXNzd29yZCIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6IjIwMTktMTEtMDhUMTc6MDQ6MjYuMTU5WiIsInZlciI6IjEuMCJ9.kuVfmgvN7_t4h2LB5o6dzTV2hngdapMrWFRPANISg5ayUnqeBMKHI5PWvISddfZ2qjO7kSPXlYVffhjrBhqAxY75EAhLX8hAmHDm_2jl49prtnsnqV-l-zhFaqCyfhEcgtVCRE_GX6EON2pewsX09Vdbn_2uHvh5wcGdWCnontzkZdrf__X8-tuE5R7tHrtge0ZXMdx5bCF7INKzA1YolTwxOOiYNVvZFPDKLRwa4VUf_qTKN5BmLisRVN4gmnTzGTPXjXlHZApRwJAbXR4V7VhtVQ6VcjHuyYIpp_rK0K7kQjwu0FLpE1FHZTNRwvXNI1VqyhGaanx2bM_59NyDgg
```

I just want the outside result to be equal to the inside with token.
I made some changes but the result change to UNDEFINED instead OBJECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use promises ?

Example:

```
 function requestToServer(){
    return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
        Request.post({
                "headers": { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, 
                "url": "https://corpqa.sts.ford.com/adfs/oauth2/token",
                "form": {
                    "grant_type":'client_credentials',
                    "client_id":'ad9cdf61-e863-4606-a90a-cf7b7141234',
                    "client_secret":'QmjeT5UZ0N1M0jOEcggrxgFzw-vrZY2UphAy21d5',
                    "resource":'urn:age:pcf:sss:dev',
                }
            }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.dir(error); 
            }
            resp = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log("inside: " + resp.access_token);
            resovle(resp.access_token);
            callback();
        });
    });
 }

 describe('TEste API', function(){
        var Request = require('request');
        it("api Testing in protractor", async function (callback) {

            let tokenReturn = await requestToServer();
            console.log("outside: www.example.com/?token=" + tokenReturn);
        });                                                                     
    });//------------------------- end describe
```

Comment: Hi friend! You solve my problem, thank you!

I made some changes to organize and now its working.

1 -I remove callback() function and parameter
2 - I put the var Request = require('request'); before the requestToServer() function.

Thank you!! I need to study more about Promise now!!